# How to Show CounDown Timer in Android Onesignal Custom Notification?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications, onesignal

In Onesignal for IOS live activity available, how to achieve the same in android programmatically using onesignal. We tried FCM its working fine, but we can't in Onesignal. Is it possible to create like below image in android using onesignal.[image].